# Reduplikation in der deutschen Sprache

Tags: etymology, dialect, history, morphology, swiss-german

Gemäss [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplikation_%28Sprache%29#Reduplikation_im_Deutschen) gibt es im deutschen beinahe keine Reduplikationen.
Bei uns in der Schweiz sind diese aber in der gesprochenen Sprache sehr weit verbreitet.

Beispiele dafür gibt es auch in Wikipedia, auch wenn ich nicht ganz einverstanden bin mit der Aussage, dass die Reduplikation in einer Frage diese verstärkt.

Hier im Chat habe ich erfahren, dass Reduplikationen auch in den alemannisch Dialekten im Süden Deutschlands gebräuchlich sind.

---

Mein Frage ist nun, wie das kommt.
Gab es früher in der deutschen Sprache Reduplikationen und diese sind ausgestorben, oder ist das eine lokale Eigenart?
Falls Reduplikationen schon früher im deutschen nicht verbreitet waren, woher kommen Sie dann in den alemannischen Dialekte?

Comment: Ich bin betreffend den Tags nicht ganz sicher; die Tags dürfen also gerne angepasst werden.

Comment: Ja -> Jaja. => LMAA

Comment: @Em1: jaja, schon klar, es gibt einige Reduplikationen, aber nicht in derselben Art wie im Schweizerdeutschen. ;)

Comment: Zum letzten Satz: Ich hoffe, Du weißt, dass das Schweizerdeutsche zum alemannischen Sprachraum gehört, so dass diese Beobachtung kein Wunder ist – [Alemannische Dialekte (Wikipedia)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannische_Dialekte).

Comment: @Speravir Dass die Schweiz und teile Deutschlands zum alemannischen Sprachraum gehören, war mir schon klar. Trotzdem war mir bis vor kurzem nicht bewusst, dass auch in den süddeutschen alemannischen Dialekten Reduplikationen des Öfteren anzutreffen sind.

Comment: Hast du mal die italienische/romanische Reduplikation angeschaut? Vielleicht kann man daraus was ableiten.

Answer (score 10):

#### Reduplikation- Definition

Unter einer Reduplikation wird das Wiederholen von Wörtern oder Wortteilen verstanden. Dies ist aber ein allgemeiner Begriff, der unterschiedliche Reduplikationsformen beinhaltet. Insofern können auch im nicht-mundartlichen Deutsch Reduplikationen auftreten, die aber nichts nicht mit der Reduplikation alemannischer Mundarten zu tun haben:

#### Reduplikation zur Verstärkung

Eine Wiederholung meist ganzer Wörter wird zur Verstärkung eingesetzt:

> **Achtung, Achtung,** hier spricht die Polizei!
> **Hopplahopp** ritten sie über die Felder!
> Kommt her, aber **zack-zack**!
> **Na, na,** so geht das nicht.

#### Präfixreduplikation

Manchmal werden Präfixe verdoppelt (oder vervielfacht), um die Bedeutung des jeweiligen Präfixes zu duplizieren:

> Meine **Urur**großmutter war eine tüchtige Frau.
> **Vorvor**gestern hatten wir noch schönes Wetter.
> **Überüber**morgen haben wir Examen.

#### Onomatopoetische Reduplikation und Lallworte

Auch in der Kindersprache oder in lautmalerischen Wörtern finden man häufige Reduplikationen:

> **Mama**, **Papa** und ihr **Wauwau** machen **dada**.
> Mit großem **Tamtam** kamen die Blasmusiker daher.
> **Huhu**, ich bin der **Kuckuck**!

#### Indogermanisches, gotisches und urgermanisches Präteritum

Alle indogermanischen Sprachen kennen die Reduplikation zur Bildung des Vergangenheitsform. So wurden [starke Verben in der Ablautklasse VII](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Althochdeutsch) mitunter durch Reduplikation gebildet. Diese Reduplikationen gingen aber schon im Althochdeutschen und später in einer Lautverschiebung unter.

> - **gân - gangan** *(gesprochen 'gengan')* wurde zu "gieng"
> - **haldana - heħald** wurde zu "hielt"
> - **hlaupana - lehlaup** wurde zu "lief"

Vermutlich handelt es sich bei der Reduplikation in alemannischen Mundarten um Reste urgermanischer oder gotischer Reduplikation zur Konjugation, die, wie im Übrigen auch in anderen Bereichen, nicht einer [Lautverschiebung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lautverschiebung) unterlag.

> "Ich chum cho luege" (Ich komme mir das gleich anschauen) - Reduplikation "chum cho" von kommen (ich chum[e] - ich komme)
> "Ich gang go jogge" (Ich gehe joggen) - Reduplikation "gang go" von gehen (ich gang= ich gehe) <sup>[GLU-Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9631486#9631486)</sup>

#### Weiterführende Links

[Wikipedia Reduplikation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplikation_%28Sprache%29)
[Belles Lettres: Ablautreihen und Konjugation der starken Verben im Deutschen](http://www.belleslettres.eu/print/starke-verben-ablautreihen-konjugation-v2.pdf)
[Ältere deutsche Literaturwissenschaft Bamberg: Besondere Verben](http://www.uni-bamberg.de/?id=23425)
[Echard Meineke: Einführung in das Althochdeutsche](http://books.google.de/books?id=zD180xU8Q-UC&lpg=PA269&ots=Qe41v6Zrxe&dq=reduplikation%20althochdeutsch&pg=PA269#v=onepage&q=reduplikation%20althochdeutsch&f=false)
[Wikipedia: Alemannische Grammatik](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannische_Grammatik)

Comment: Dass die alemannische Reduplikation ein urgermanischer Rest sei, ist wohl Humbug, vgl. [Go(ge) schaffe gaa - Schweizerisches Idiotikon](https://www.idiotikon.ch/wortgeschichten/go). Eine weitere Art der Reduplikation ist diejenige mit Ablaut, z.B. Zickzack, Krimskrams, Mischmasch, Singsang, Wirrwarr oder lautmalerische Bildungen wie ticktack, schnippschnapp usw.